# Hide Empty Elements From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a datatable that is using standard features (pagination, sorting, searching, date range, etc.), but I also have a portion at the bottom of the table that displays the total by office.  What I would like to implement, however, is a means of hiding any search results that would display as "0" for an office.  For instance, if you search my table for "assistant" then Edinburgh, London, Singapore and Tokyo all display a result of "0" (since there are no assistants for any of those offices).  Instead of showing those empty results how could I instead hide them?

Here is a link to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/l337method/vhoupanz/

Here is my script:

```
var offices = api.column(2).data().sort().unique().toArray();
var totals = [];
for (var i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) totals.push(0);

api.rows({filter:'applied'}).every(function() {
    var data = this.data();
    totals[offices.indexOf(data[2])] += intVal(data[5]);
    });

html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) {
    html += '<br>' + offices[i] + ': ' + totals[i];
    }
    html += '<br'

$(api.column(4).footer()).html(html);
```

Comment: in the `for` loop, you can just add an `if (totals[i] > 0)`

Comment: Or simply `if(totals[i])`. Considering that there will be no negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) {
    if(totals[i] > 0){
         html += '<br>' + offices[i] + ': ' + totals[i];
    }
}
html += '<br'
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  I am not sure why the syntax was throwing me off so badly.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```js
html = [];
for (var i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) {
  if (totals[i] > 0) html.push(offices[i] + ': ' + totals[i]);
}

$(api.column(4).footer()).html(html.length == 0?"":html.join('</br>'));
```